# docker with two separated php-services on one php container

Tags: php, nginx, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

i have docker-compose.yml with content:

```
nginx:
build: ./nginx/
ports:
    - 80:80
links:
    - php
volumes:
    - ./code:/var/www/
    - ./nginx/site.local.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.local.conf
    - ./nginx/api.local.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/api.local.conf
php:
    build: ./php/
    expose:
        - 9000
    volumes:
        - ./code/cms:/var/www/site
        - ./code/www:/var/www/api
```

on my local machine i can get all hosts separate site.local & api.local

but i have one problem and can't resolve it:

there in php requests from site.local to api.local, so i get errors like this:

**cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: api.local**

could anybody help me? thanks.

Comment: I think that you have an indentation problem with the `nginx` container, shouldn't `build`, `ports`, `links` and `volumes` be indented under `nginx:` as you did with the `php:` container ?

Comment: @Marcs i think problem is not in it, because is is some of standard designing **nginx + php-fpm***. I could ping site.local and api.local from **nginx** container and proxying to php, because of linking, but i can't ping any domain from **php** container.

Comment: There's nothing in your docker-compose.yml paste that explains where api.local and site.local are defined to be resolved. Is this some DNS setting you have created for your entire local network? Is there something in the Dockerfile for nginx or php that has anything to do with resolving those?

Comment: @programmerq it is just in nginx configs, for example:
```server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.local;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/api.local.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/api.local.error.log;
    root /var/www/api/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   php:9000;
        fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV dev;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an answer on my question!

```
version: "2"

networks:
    lan_0:
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
            driver: default
            config:
                - subnet: 172.19.0.0/24
                  gateway: 172.19.0.21

services:
    nginx:
        build: ./nginx/
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        links:
            - php
        volumes:
            - ./code:/var/www/
        networks:
            lan_0:
                ipv4_address: 172.19.0.22
    php:
        build: ./php/
        expose:
            - 9000
        volumes:
            - ./code:/var/www
        extra_hosts:
            - "api.local:172.19.0.22"
            - "site.local:172.19.0.22"
        networks:
            lan_0:
                ipv4_address: 172.19.0.23
```

That is example, how to communicate two web-application in one php-container.